# Leiningen only runs in one directory

Tags: installation, clojure, leiningen

I'm currently attempting to work through "Clojure for the Brave and True" ([in particular, trying to set it up](https://www.braveclojure.com/getting-started/)) and I'm running into some trouble. I'm on Windows 10 so I installed Leiningen according to the instructions on [the website](https://leiningen.org/), but the lein commands only work on the Desktop where I installed it, not in the actual project folder which is located *on* the desktop (navigating to the actual folder does not let me run it; using `lein run` on the Desktop simply results in the error "No :main namespace specified in project.clj."

Have I done something wrong in installing leiningen?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to edit your `Path` environment variable to add the folder where you installed the `lein.bat` file, or you could just provide the full path to that file instead of just `lein` when you're working in a different folder.

I would recommend creating a folder on your `C:` drive to put `lein.bat` in, and adding that folder to `Path` instead of desktop. I typically used to have `C:\lein\` with `lein.bat` in that folder.

Comment: I just installed it from C:\Windows and that worked, since it is already in the Path environment variable. Thanks!